# Rails 5.1 app with Vue and webpacker 3, css not compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpacker

I'm trying to add [Element UI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart) to my Vue app. 
I follow the quick start tutorial and I have my application.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/it'
import App from '../app.vue'

Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  const app = new Vue(App).$mount('app')

  console.log(app)
})
```

I'm importing the CSS and I have also

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

Inside my layout, but this file is empty, no styles. 
The app is working, but without the CSS.
Where is my fault?

Comment: maybe this search query can help ? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=using+vue+js+library+with+ruby+on+rails&atb=v52-6_b&ia=web

Comment: No, i follow every tutorial. The problem is the CSS compiling

Comment: so you import the css with those `import` statements?

Comment: I follow this https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/775

Comment: ok. I did not read everything there. The question is, is this a `Rails` issue or a `Webpacker`/`frontend` issue. Questions that include many different technologies (*full-stack*) usually get less attention. While If you can identify this as either a frontend or backend issue. You probably get more help

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I use stylesheet_link_tag instead of stylesheet_pack_tag

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the import method

Use

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Instead of

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

based on: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/987

Comment: Or both, in case you still use rails asset stylesheets